# Использование различных версий библиотек в одном приложении

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc, компоновщик

В приложении, которое линкуется с библиотеками OpenCV *третьей* версии, потребовалось встроить модуль, который использует для линковки библиотеки *другой* версии OpenCV, отличной от исходной (которые поставляются вместе с этим модулем).

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно собирать такой проект? Может можно как-то указать, что объектные файлы, которые используют модуль, должны линковаться с старыми библиотеками, а все остальные - с новыми?

Comment: Вернее всего будет собрать этот модуль в виде отдельного исполняемого файла.

Comment: @VTT, как вариант :)

Comment: я не смотрел, а можно ли собрать разные версии `opencv`, чтобы у них были разные `namespace`'ы? тогда символы не будут пересекаться и это избавит от львиной доли проблем...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если честно - не знаю :)